# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType with retrofit2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, retrofit2, classcastexception, android-r8

I have this code:

```
    val profile: UserProfile = userApi.profile()


    @GET("users/profile")
    suspend fun profile(): UserProfile
```

When i run userApi.profile() i get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType
```

Details: I updated gradle, some libraries, kotlin version and android studio. This code used to work before updates. Nothing changed on backend side.

Update: looks like this is happening to all api calls, not just this one.

```
retrofitVersion = 2.9.0
kotlinVersion = 1.8.10
gradle = 8.0
```

Answer (score 18):

If you check this link https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/3751 it will tell you to add these in your `proguard-rules.pro` file

```
# Keep generic signature of Call, Response (R8 full mode strips signatures from non-kept items). 
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking interface retrofit2.Call 
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class retrofit2.Response 
  
 # With R8 full mode generic signatures are stripped for classes that are not 
 # kept. Suspend functions are wrapped in continuations where the type argument 
 # is used. 
 -keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

Comment: The background here is that [AGP 8.0 enables R8 full mode by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77652435/56285). For me the rules in this answer fixed the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Add these two lines to your proguard rules file

```bash
-keep class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite { *; }
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking class kotlin.coroutines.Continuation
```

If you don't know what is your proguard rules file, check your `app\build.gradle` file. There should be a few lines like:

```kotlin
buildTypes {
    getByName("release") {
        isMinifyEnabled = true
        proguardFiles(
            getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
            "proguard-rules.pro",
        )
    }
}
```

`proguard-rules.pro` is your proguard rules file.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why this would happen after update to **Android Gradle plugin 8.x** is this (from [8.0.0 release notes](https://developer.android.com/build/releases/past-releases/agp-8-0-0-release-notes)):

> AGP 8.0 enables R8 full mode by default. For more details, see [R8 full mode](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md#r8-full-mode).

For me, the additional `-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking` rules **[in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77300397/56285)** fixed the problem.

Alternatively you could explicitly disable full mode by setting this in `gradle.properties`:

```
android.enableR8.fullMode=false
```

That said, it seems preferable to keep full mode on, if possible. Further reading:

- [R8 FAQ](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8/+/refs/heads/master/compatibility-faq.md)
- [What does R8 Full Mode really do? (aggressive optimizations)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58726616/56285)

Answer (score 0):

While other answers are correct, however, I believe they're correct until Retrofit `2.9.0`.
After upgrading to Retrofit `2.10.0` again, I encountered a similar error.

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to retrofit2.ServiceMethod
```

I already added necessary rules for progaurd since `2.9.0` but it didn't matter. I didn't remove those rules yet, but I think those rules are unnecessary since introduction of the [`retrofit-response-type-keeper`](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/trunk/retrofit-response-type-keeper#readme). Furthermore, I also used `moshi` so adding its codegen artifact and annotating all my models with `@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)` fixed the problem for me.